# What is the best solution for deploying a Spring batch in Azure?

Tags: azure, spring-batch

I have several Spring Batch and Java batch that I want to deploy in Azure.
These jobs process file zip (several text files, xml... inside). 
Today they turn in a tomcat (24/24 - 7/7), just for one run per month.

I want to deploy them in azure to reduce costs and launch them as soon as a file arrives in the blob storage.

I saw that there were two options:

- Azure function -> But I need to archive the input and output files, and the processing of an entry zip can be quite long
- Azure WebJobs -> I feel like we have to let the machine run

Do you have other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to repackage your jobs as Spring Boot apps and run them on demand when necessary. Having a Tomcat running 24/7 on a cloud environment to trigger a batch job once a month is not ideal in terms of resources consumption and in terms of dollars on your bill :-)

Here are two quick guides on how to package a Spring Batch job as a Boot app and how to deploy a Boot app to MS Azure:

- [Creating a batch service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/)
- [Deploying a Spring Boot app to Azure](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-for-azure/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud :), my Spring Batch are already packaged in Spring Boot App.
But on your links, we launch the application Spring Boot 24/7, it is possible to put a trigger on AppService ?

Comment: Yes, this because the second guide was about a web app, but the first guide shows a batch app. I'm not that familiar with Azure, but you need to see how to trigger a java process (`java -jar mybatchjob.jar`) in Azure according to your requirement.